# Fixed width table with second column dynamic width and ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I need a two column table that has only one row. The data in the first column should always display in full, but the second column should resize and the data in it should ellipse if it can't fit in the cell. If the first column expands to fit its data, the second column should contract, all while keeping the table width the same.

I tried to fix width of table and all kinds of ways to achieve this with CSS, but I couldn't figure out. It does seem like it's something that should be achievable.

This is how the table should behave with different data in the first column:

[image]

[image]

```css
.ellipsis {
  width: 190px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>table width always the same</h3>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      Column1
    </th>
    <th>
      Column2
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Display in full</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="ellipsis">Ellipsis this if length is too long</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you have to use `table` layout based? You can use flexbox to achieve this.

Comment: I'd just care that I could put it inside a div and make it look like a table. What would I need to use from flexbox?

Comment: This is an approach using flexbox. If it fits to your requirements, I'll put it as answer with explanations: https://jsbin.com/ferixiq/edit?html,css,output

Comment: This is very close. I added a third scenario which shows that the second column should not contract if the data does not fill all of it.

Comment: So, the parent should has fixed width?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The parent should always be the same width in all three scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mention in the comments, it can be achieved using `flex-box`.

- `.parent` has `display: flexbox`
- Column 1 has `white-space: nowrap` to make it fit its content.
- Column 2 has `flex-grow` so it will take all the remain space.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.parent > div:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.parent > div:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.parent div:last-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.parent > div > div {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="header">Column1</div>
    <div>Display in full</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="header">Column 2</div>
    <div>Ellipsis this if length is too long</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsbin.com/ferixiq/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thank you. This is awesome, man! You may want to add `,output` at the end of your jsbin link so it's enabled by default.